# Split 2D NumPy array of strings on "," character

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a 2D NumPy of strings array like:
`a = array([['1,2,3'], ['3,4,5']], dtype=object)` and I would like to convert it into a 2D Numpy array like this: `a = array([['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']])`. I would then like to also convert the strings to floats, so the final array would look like this: `a = array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not a numpy array.

Comment: You should probably try and read your data into a proper NumPy array in the first place, rather than clean up the mess like this.

Comment: I first loaded the data onto a Pandas data frame object and then extracted a single column. Wouldn't that give me a NumPy array? Then I reshaped it so that it became a 2D array.

Comment: You may have extracted a NumPy array, but what you show us is _not_ a NumPy array. We cannot answer your question by taking guesses.

Comment: Have I shown a NumPy array now?

Comment: Your input and output differ a lot. Can you cross-check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an object array, we might as well iterate and use plain python split:

```
In [118]: a = np.array([['1,2,3'], ['3,4,5']], dtype=object)
In [119]: a.shape
Out[119]: (2, 1)
In [120]: np.array([x.split(',') for x in a.ravel()])
Out[120]: 
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['3', '4', '5']], dtype='<U1')
In [122]: np.array([x.split(',') for x in a.ravel()],dtype=float)
Out[122]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [3., 4., 5.]])
```

I raveled it to simplify iteration.  Plus the result doesn't need that 2nd size 1 dimension.

There is a `np.char` function that applies `split` to elements of an array, but the result is messier:

```
In [129]: a.astype(str)
Out[129]: 
array([['1,2,3'],
       ['3,4,5']], dtype='<U5')
In [130]: np.char.split(_, sep=',')
Out[130]: 
array([[list(['1', '2', '3'])],
       [list(['3', '4', '5'])]], dtype=object)
In [138]: np.stack(Out[130].ravel()).astype(float)
Out[138]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [3., 4., 5.]])
```

Another way:

```
In [132]: f = np.frompyfunc(lambda astr: np.array(astr.split(','),float),1,1)
In [133]: f(a)
Out[133]: 
array([[array([1., 2., 3.])],
       [array([3., 4., 5.])]], dtype=object)
In [136]: np.stack(_.ravel())
Out[136]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [3., 4., 5.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through rows and use `split(',')` to split each row at the commas, and put the result in a new numpy array with a numeric data type:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['1,2,3'], ['3,4,5']])
b = np.array([x[0].split(',') for x in a], dtype=np.float32)
print(b)

#[[ 1.  2.  3.]
# [ 3.  4.  5.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose this if you don't mind having them as a vector

```
np.array([["asa,asd"], ["dasd,asdaf,asfasf"]], dtype=object)
Out[31]: 
array([['asa,asd'],
      ['dasd,asdaf,asfasf']], dtype=object)
np.concatenate(np.char.split(Out[31].astype(str), ",").ravel())
Out[32]: array(['asa', 'asd', 'dasd', 'asdaf', 'asfasf'], dtype='<U6')
```