# Splitting and collecting multi-word strings into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, string, nlp

I have an array `arr` of strings, each of which I would like to split by (' ') and then gather again into an array of words

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['foo bar baz', 'foo baz bar' 'bar foo baz'], dtype=object)
```

output should look something like:

```
array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz'])
```

Why does the following command throw an error and what is the correct method ?

```
np.char.split(arr, sep = ' ')

TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50459578/6692898, I don't know why I can't find that question when trying to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
res = np.array(' '.join(arr).split())
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'baz', 'barbar', 'foo', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code doesn't work is that you specified the **dtype** as **object**
You should change it to **str**

```
arr = np.array(['foo bar baz', 'foo baz bar', 'bar foo baz'], dtype=str)
np.char.split(arr, sep = ' ')
>>> array([list(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']), list(['foo', 'baz', 'bar']),
   list(['bar', 'foo', 'baz'])], dtype=object)
```

As we can see, the output gives a list for each string on the original array, all you have to do is concatenate them

```
np.concatenate(np.char.split(arr, sep=' '))
>>> array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz'],
  dtype='<U3')
```